# Enum in URI Template?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I'm using a WCF Restful service with routing tables.

I'm trying to make use of an enumeration to control how the output is serialized, but I'm having trouble.  For instance, I have the following enum:

```
public enum outputType
{
    JSON, XML, XML_XSD, CSV, TXT
}
```

Then I try to make use of with a simple test call.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{ot}/test")]
public Stream test(outputType ot)
{
   using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("test"))
   {
      //build dummy datatable
      dt.Columns.Add("col1");
      dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
      dt.Rows[0]["col1"] = "asdf";

      //serialize results
      //takes a datatable and serializes it into the outputType's file format
      return _m.serialize(ot, dt);
   }
}
```

Which compiles fine, but gives me the error "Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.".

I know I could change the ot variable to type string and hack some validation together, but I would rather use the framework correctly.  How can I do this?

I'm concerned if I have to hack together my own solution, I will have to add a validation function to every single one of my webservice entry points which would be rather messy.

Comment: What type of arguments does the Serialize method take?

Comment: Altered initial question to reflect responses to comments.  For this example serialize just takes in a datatable and outputs it into the format specified by the outputType enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change parameter type to `string` and convert to `Enum`

```
public Stream test(string ot) {
    ot = ot ?? "XML";

    try {
        OutputType kind = Enum.Parse(typeof(OutputType), ot);
        . . . 
    }catch(ArgumentException e) }
       . . .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great solution, but you could do this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "json/test")]
public Stream testJSON()
{
    return test(outputType.JSON);
}

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "xml/test")]
public Stream testXML()
{
    return test(outputType.XML);
}

...

private Stream test(outputType ot)
{
   using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("test"))
   {
      //build dummy datatable
      dt.Columns.Add("col1");
      dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
      dt.Rows[0]["col1"] = "asdf";

      //serialize results
      return _m.serialize(outputType, dt);
   }
}
```